# Are these two proofs regarding coloring valid and complete?

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing

Question #1) Prove or disprove: If G is a graph and for every vertex $v \in V(G), \chi (G-v) < \chi (G)$, then for every subgraph H such that $H \neq G, \chi(H) < \chi(G)$.

Question #2) Prove or disprove: If G is a graph and for every edge $e \in E(G), \chi (G-e) < \chi (G)$, then for every subgraph H such that $H \neq G, \chi(H) < \chi(G)$.

My response:

Solution #1) Since deleting any vertex from G results in fewer colorings, we can assume that every vertex is needed to maintain $\chi(G)$. So, since by definition every subgraph H has $V(H) \subseteq V(G)$, it follows that $\chi(H) < \chi(G)$. Therefore, $\chi(H) < \chi(G)$.

Solution #2) When we contract any edge from G, we merge the connecting vertices, and thus $V(G)$ decreases. We follow the same logic
presented in solution #1 to find that $\chi(H) < \chi(G)$.

So are these responses both valid and complete? If not, how can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first proof is not correct.  It would be hard to make a correct proof since the claim is false.  The main point is that there are subgraphs of $G$ that are not *induced subgraphs*.  An induced subgraph of $G$ is a subgraph obtained by just deleting vertices.  The claim is true for induced subgraphs of course.

In fact, Claim 1 fails rather spectacularly.  In 1970 Dirac conjectured that there exists a vertex critical graph (a graph satisfying the hypothesis of Question 1), but where *every* edge is not critical.  That is for all $e \in E(G)$, $\chi(G - e)=\chi(G)$.  This was proved in this [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X9290354I) of Brown.

The second claim is true (provided $G$ does not contain isolated vertices), but your proof needs some more work. In particular, Claim 2 refers to edge *deletion*, not edge *contraction*.

Comment: Fantastic response, thank you! It looks like I have some more work to do.